# Converting mysql TIME from 24 HR to AM/PM format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I want to display the TIME field from my mysql table on my website, but rather than showing 21:00:00 etc I want to show 8:00 PM. I need a function/code to do this or even any pointers in the right direction. Will mark the first reply with some code as the correct reply.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

I'd imagine you'd want date_format().

Example: DATE_FORMAT($date, "%r")

Comment: it will display in AM/PM format. but what if i wanted to input AM/PM format type to mysql time format?

Answer (score 18):

Show the date & time data in AM/PM format with the following example...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`t`.`date_field`,'%h:%i %p') AS `date_field` FROM `table_name` AS `t`
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`t`.`date_field`,'%r') AS `date_field` FROM `table_name` AS `t`
```

Both are working properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can also select the column as a unix timestamp using MYSQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function. Then format it in PHP. IMO this is more flexible...

```
select a, b, c, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(instime) as unixtime;
```

The in PHP use the `date()` function & format it any way you want.

```
<?php echo date('Y/m/d', $row->unixtime); ?>
```

The reason I like this method as opposed to formatting it in SQL is b/c, to me, the date's format is a display decision & (in my opinion) formatting the date in SQL feels wrong... why put display logic in your SQL?

Now - if you're not processing the data in PHP and are doing adhoc queries then `DATE_FORMAT()` is the way to go. But if you're gonna have the data show up on the web I'd go with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and do the formatting in PHP...

I mean... lets say you want to change how the date & time are displayed on the page... wouldn't it feel "off" to have to modify your SQL for a display tweak?

my 2 cents

Comment: I have a class that contains all of my date handling code. In the login code I just call a function from that class which formats the time using DATE_FORMAT(). So it doesn't really show in the display code and doesn't feel off

Mysql dates are just more readable than unix timestamps.

Comment: +1 for saying "the date's format is a display decision" indeed it is, I agree with you 200% on this

Answer (score 2):

Use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

DATE_FORMAT(<Fieled>,'%h:%i:%s %p')

or

DATE_FORMAT(<Fieled>,'%r')

Answer (score 2):

I had been trying to do the same and got this page returned from a Google search. I worked a solution for the time 21:00:00;

- using `DATE_FORMAT(<field>,'%l.%i%p')` which returned 9.00PM
- putting a `LOWER()` function around it to return 9.00pm

So the full code is; `DATE_FORMAT(<field>,'%l.%i%p')`

Worked OK for me ...