# Retrieving date format with am/pm in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have converted date to my local time as below:

```
$this->date_string = "%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s";
  $timestamp = now();
  $timezone = 'UP45';
  $daylight_saving = TRUE;
  $time =  gmt_to_local($timestamp, $timezone, $daylight_saving);
$this->updated_date = mdate($this->date_string,$time);
```

And I'm storing this field in to database.

Now at retrieval time I want format like this:
    "11-04-2011 4:50:00 PM"

I have used this code:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($rs->updated_date);
$date1 = "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %a";
$updat1 = date($date1,$timestamp);
```

But this will give me only

```
"11-04-2011 4:50:00 AM"
```

But I have stored it like it was PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might get voted down, but will have a go at it.
Is it because the MySQL stores it in 24 hour format? (assuming you are using the datetime field type)

Maybe this will help
[Converting mysql TIME from 24 HR to AM/PM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173005/converting-mysql-time-from-24-hr-to-am-pm-format)
sorry if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes I have field type datetime and i was storing the datetime in 12 hours format. so i get that problem. Now i have changed this right now i am storing the datetime in 24 hours format. so my problem is sloved here.