# mysql str to time

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at the time functions but need help to convert time from

"18:00:00" to 6 PM in the SQL language.

Comment: There's no such thing as 6 PM in SQL. Do you mean the literal string `"6 PM"`? As in `"00:00:00"` becomes `"12 AM"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting mysql TIME from 24 HR to AM/PM format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173005/converting-mysql-time-from-24-hr-to-am-pm-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string to a `time` and then convert the value to a string using `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(cast('18:00:00' as time), '%h %p')
```