# Laravel Everything Displaying Except My Time

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date

I have an events view, where users can create any event and all events will be viewable on the Events page.  For some reason all the data shows on my table except for my `Time` column.

I have some code here, hopefully it'll give some clues as to why it's showing up as empty in my table view.

**Events Controller**

```html
public function event()
{
  $events = Event::all();
  return view('pages.event', compact('events'));
}

public function createEvent()
{
  return view('pages.createevent');
}

public function newEvent()
{
  $event = Event::create(Request::only(
    'name',
    'description',
    'location',
    'time',
    'start_date',
    'end_date'
    ));

  $event->save();

  \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Event Created Successfully!');

  return redirect('event');
}
```

**Events View**

```html
<table class=" display table table-hover table-bordered" , id="event">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Functions</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($events as $event)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $event->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->description }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->location }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->time }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->start_date }}</td>
      <td>{{ $event->end_date }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;"><a href="pages/editevents/{{$event['id']}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Edit</a>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="display:inline; margin-right:auto;"><a href="deleteEvent/{{$event['id']}}">Delete</a>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The time is inserted into my database just fine, but it's just not displaying in my view.

**Data Types**

[image: Data Types]

**Table in DB**

[image: Table in Database]

**Events View**
[image: Events View]

Does it have something to do with my `time` data type? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**Events Model**

```html
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
/**
 * Class Events
 */
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Events';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'location',
        'time',
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: be consistent and use lower case.. no Time but time (in database).

Comment: @Kyslik Thank you for helping, i've changed it in my database to lowercase.  It's showing now.  Would you happen to know how to format it to 12hr AM/PM instead of 24hr? Thanks again!

Comment: In future use google, http://ideone.com/NkvsjN

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$event->Time` *with a capital letter*, because that's how your column is defined. Model properties are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, I created the table in MySqlWorkbench then created the model in Laravel.  My data type in the table is a `time` type, should I switch it to datetime, and use the `$event->time->toDateTimeString()` as you suggested? My `start_date and end_date` display fine.

Comment: Try `dd($event->time);` in your controller to see what the type of this property is.

Comment: I get an error message `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$time`

Comment: Can you post your model too?

Comment: @JDubbleU can you also try `dd($event->Time)` with a capital. You field your DB is `Time`, but you're trying to access it like `time`. :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I changed `Time` to `time` in my database, do you know how to format the string to show it in 12hr AM/PM format instead of 24hr? Thank you so much!

Comment: @JDubbleU Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173005/converting-mysql-time-from-24-hr-to-am-pm-format